# When do the kernels of surjective morphisms $\mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/f\mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots,x_n]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ have trivial intersection?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, multivariate-polynomial

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra. We write $|\mathcal{F}|$ for the set of surjective algebra homomorphisms $\mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and we say $\mathcal{F}$ is *geometric* when $\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{F}):=\bigcap\limits_{p\in|\mathcal{F}|}\ker p=\{0\}$.

Let $f\in\mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. When is $\mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/f\mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ geometric?

Here's what I know so far: any algebra homomorphism $\mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/f\mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is a homomorphism out of $\mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ which sends $f$ to $0$ - in other words, it is evaluation at a root of $f$. Thus $[g]\in\mathcal{I}(\mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/f\mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots,x_n])$ when $g$ is $0$ on all roots of $f$. Hence $\mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/f\mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is geometric when a polynomial being $0$ on the roots of $f$ implies it is a multiple of $f$.

Since $\mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is a UFD, writing $f$ as the product $P_1^{\alpha_1}\dots P_k^{\alpha_k}$ of powers of pairwise distinct non-constant irreducible polynomials $P_i$, we note $f$ is $0$ exactly when $P_1\dots P_n$ is. Hence a necessary condition is that $f\mid P_1\dots P_n$, so $\alpha_i=1$ for all $i$.

We also notice if the roots of $P_i$ are a subset of the roots of $P_j$, $f$ is $0$ exactly when $f/P_i$. If the quotient is geometric then $f\mid f/P_i$, so another necessary condition is that this never occurs. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question and I'm here to tell you that it's not so easy to answer in general. Your work so far is good, and your deduction that $f$ must be squarefree is correct, and there's not a whole lot more in terms of easy conditions one can give on $f$.

$\bigcap_{p\in|\mathcal{F}|} \ker p=0$ is the case exactly when $(f)=I(V_{\Bbb R}(f))$ - that is, when $\mathcal{F}$ is the coordinate algebra of a real variety in some $\Bbb R^n$. The kernel you care about is the quotient of $I(V_{\Bbb R}(f))$ (all the functions in $\Bbb R[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ vanishing where $f$ does) by $(f)$. By the real Nullstellensatz, $I(V_{\Bbb R}(f))$ is the *real radical* of $(f)$, also denoted $\sqrt[\Bbb R]{(f)}$, and it may be described as the ideal $$\{ p\in\Bbb R[x_1,\cdots,x_n] \mid \exists m\in\Bbb Z_{>0}, \exists q_j\in\Bbb R[x_1,\cdots,x_n] \text{ such that } p^{2m}+\sum_j q_j^2\in I\}.$$

This is not so easy to compute in general. One source of difficulty is that if some element of $(f)$ can be written as a sum of squares $\sum_i f_i^2$, then each $f_i$ belongs to the real radical - so you have to be able to understand all the ways in which multiples of $f$ decompose in to sums of squares in order to compute this. For instance, if $f=x^2+y^2$, a perfectly respectable irreducible polynomial, then $\sqrt[\Bbb R]{(x^2+y^2)}=(x,y)$.

In general, there are algorithms available to compute $\sqrt[\Bbb R]{I}$, but I don't know the current state of the field very well - I'm under the impression that it's still an active area of research, with some new techniques showing up even this year. A cursory search of the literature gives "Computations of real radicals of polynomial ideals" by Becker and Neuhaus ([doi link](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-2752-6_1)) and part II, by Neuhaus alone ([doi link](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-4049(96)00103-X), includes full article) as the start of published work in the area, and "Computing real radicals by moment optimization" by Baldi and Mourrain ([arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.09367)) from earlier this year as the most modern thing I can find.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Definitely didn't expect it to be so complicated, haha (this problem is an exercise in a textbook).

Comment: You're welcome - what text, if I may ask? The top-line conclusion is not actually so bad - $\mathcal{F}$ is geometric if it's the coordinate algebra of a real variety - but the ways we have of verifying that are not the best.

Comment: "Smooth Manifolds and Observables" by Jet Nestruev, Exercise 3.9 number 2 - I do hope I haven't horribly misinterpreted the question!